# Cannot create new website in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a new `.NET` website in Visual Studio 2010, but when I go to create a new web site (File>New>Web Site...) I am left with no options to select. Am I missing something? I've searched all around and can't find any way to download templates.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Templates are not installed in your system.
Close all instance of Visual Studio. Open visual studio command prompt and type,

```
devenv/installvstemplates
```

Press Enter. Wait for the process to complete and the open Visual Studio.
You will get all missing templates under Visual Studio installed templates.

Comment: This leads me to believe I incorrectly installed it, as I don't have this vs command prompt.